# Compute likelihood of sample belonging to model lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I would like to use mixed effects models in order to create a classifier based on a single measurement. In order to do this I need to calculate the likelihood of a new sample belonging to a given model. Meaning I have created two models using lme4:

```
Pro <-  lmer(measure ~ time  + (1|sample), data=positive)
Neg <-  lmer(measure ~ time  + (1|sample), data=negative)
```

For a new sample (its measurement) I would like to compute the likelihood of belonging to each of the models, and compare.

P(sample | model). That is, given a measure (y) what is the likelihood this is a positive sample.

By selection the model with the highest likelihood I am able to classify the sample as positive or negative.

Is there a simple way to do this in lme4 or other R package?

EDIT: terms used

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "a sample belonging to a model". Samples are drawn from populations. I also don't understand why you don't create one model instead of two.

Comment: I agree samples are drawn from populations apologies if my terms are incorrect. a model is attempt to represent that population. I am building two models in order to represent two "separate" populations.